# How to encrypt certain tables in mysql

Tags: java, mysql, encryption

Currently I am doing parent portal (a portal for parents to monitor their children's school activities).

I want to encrypt certain tables in the database such as the `children result` so that it cannot be accessed by anyone. Due to my lack of database knowledge, I could not think of ways to encrypt.

Can anyone with the knowledge help me with it?

Comment: Personally I would change your business logic not to allow direct access to the DB.

Comment: Before sending to database, you can call sha1 encryption and then at retrieving, call sha1 decryption    https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SHA-1

Comment: @makdu sha1 is a one-way hash function, there is no notion of sha1 encryption and even less of a notion of sha1 decryption

Comment: Tried to make it easier to read with minor grammatical and syntax fixes

Comment: I think you can try freeware software for encrypting database first. I have using mydiamo for free.

Answer (score 1):

From my point of view, what you are basically asking here is

> I have this database that holds sensitive information... and I don't trust it

First of all, this is where you should stop and reevaluate your reasoning.  Why don't you trust your database? And then you should change your infrastructure so that you can trust your database with sensitive information using tools that have already been built by the database developer or other third parties.

If your response to that is that you actually trust your database very much but you want an added layer of protection that isn't really necessary then this is a very basic example of what you *could* do.

Before procceeding

> You are almost guaranteed to get something wrong if you do encryption
>   yourself.

And the following example is no exception, it has plenty of issues with it. You should know that this example has vulnerabilities that are unacceptable in a production environment and it is meant as a basic suggestion to get you started. If you are going to pursue encrypted database fields, then you should really get some professional help.  This is not something to take lightly... you've been warned.

1. Identify what data (table columns) is sensitive. Personal information, financial records, ect.
2. Ensure that you do not need to order based on these columns (`ORDER BY children.first_name` will not work if the children.first_name column is encrypted in the database)
3. Change the data types of the fields apprpriately (if they are integer fields then you are going to need to change them to TEXT or some other CHAR field)
4. In your application, Encrypt the fields when writing to the database, Decrypt them when reading: Use AES256 and a **randomly** generated key that you keep **very** secure. You could even look at tools like [Hashicorp Vault](https://www.vaultproject.io) to programmatically retrieve this key at runtime.  This way the key is never persisted to the application server's hard drive and is just kept in memory.

And now you have **theoretically** restricted the attack surface of your service to your application servers and **theoretically** made it very hard for anyone to extract data from your database should they get their hands on the data.  Again start by asking "Why don't I trust my database? How could someone get their hands on this data?" then go from there.

Remember that passwords should be **Hashed** and salted, not encrypted